# beamer + tikz box position

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning

I am trying to put multiple boxes on a slide with tikz. If the slide contains just one box, everything seems to be fine, but once i put another box, this changes the position of the first box by a little. All the positioning needs to be absolute. Is there any chance to make this work?

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[sumlimits,intlimits]{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{ddef}{Def.}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem*{ther}{Th.}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{obs}{Observation}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{ex}{Ex.}
\def\d{{\rm d}}
\def\inf{\infty}
\newcommand{\iu}{{i\mkern1mu}}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.2cm,text margin right=0.2cm}
\tikzset{
  every overlay node/.style={
    draw=black,fill=white,rounded corners,anchor=north east,
  },
}
\setitemize{label=\usebeamerfont*{itemize item}%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}
  \usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}

\setlength{\mathindent}{10pt}
% Usage:
% \tikzoverlay at (-1cm,-5cm) {content};
% or
% \tikzoverlay[text width=5cm] at (-1cm,-5cm) {content};
\def\tikzoverlay{%
   \tikz[overlay]\node[every overlay node]
}%

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Examples}

    {\footnotesize
    \tikzoverlay[text width=5.3cm] at ([xshift=-0.4cm,yshift=-0.3cm] current page.north east) {
        {
        \tiny
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=5mm]
            \item $J^\alpha f(t) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^t \left( t-u \right)^{\alpha-1}f(u)\,\d u$
            \item $D_R^\alpha f(t) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(n-\alpha)}\frac{\d^n}{\d t^n} \int_0^t (t-u)^{n-\alpha-1}f(u)\,\d u$
            \item $D_C^\alpha f(t) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(n-\alpha)} \int_0^t (t-u)^{n-\alpha-1} f^{(n)}(u)\,\d u$
        \end{itemize}
        }
    };

        \tikzoverlay[text width=4.3cm] at ([xshift=-0.4cm,yshift=-0.3cm] current page.north east) {
        {
        \tiny
        \begin{obs}
            $D_R^\alpha t^{\alpha-1}= 0$. Also note, if $\beta\le n-1$, $D_C^\alpha t^\beta \equiv 0$ which is not true about $D_R^\alpha t^\beta$!
        \end{obs}
        }
    };  
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Another issue I am having is that the absolute positioning that I am using does not work once I use shrink on the frame. Is there any way to really do absolute positioning in beamer with tikz? (btw, it works with shrink with textpos but textpos but textpos seems too complicated to work with (rounded boxes,etc).

Comment: Maybe look into the `overlay,remember picture` keys of `tikz`?

Comment: If the above keys don't help, can you please post a compilable MWE? Even after adding missing `}` I just get a white frame?

Comment: Please, reduce your code to a minimum and limit question to only one problem (positioning of boxes).